# Dell poweredge R640 disable USB 3.0 possible?

Tags: vmware-esxi, dell-poweredge, usb

Everything is in the title.

I want to install an old ESXI (5.5 version) on a DELL PowerEdge, but just after finishing the boot of ESXI every USB devices (Mouse + keyboard) seems to turn off and I can't even do the first step of the installation. I read on internet that the cause could be ESXI 5.5 which does not support USB 3.0. It's advised to disable USB 3.0 in the BIOS following this way :

`System BIOS Settings > Integrated Devices > USB 3.0 => Disable`

BUT I don't find this option in Integrated devices.

So I guess we can do it on the most recent servers but not the R640 ?

Answer (score 2):

To make it simple, plug your devices in the front usb port for the initial setup, and remotely connect to the server after the setup.

***The PowerEdge R640 system supports:***

**USB 2.0-compliant port on the front panel**

Micro USB 2.0-compliant port in the front panel

NOTE: The micro USB 2.0-compliant port on the front panel can only be used as an iDRAC Direct or a management port.

USB 3.0-compliant ports on the back panel

NOTE: One optional USB 3.0-compliant port on the front panel for 4 x 3.5 and 8 x 2.5 inch hard drive systems.

Internal USB 3.0-compliant port

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I finally installed ESXI 6.7 because ESXI 5.5 is no longer supported by Vmware... So I didn't try your advice sorry :)